# Key with version number error in YugabyteDB cluster?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm just testing yugabyte under some negative tests and I'm facing a kind of issue. I'm running a 3 node cluster (master and tserver running on same node) When I stop one node and start it up again,  T-server is not booting up under this log

```
F20220506 06:50:49 ../../src/yb/tserver/tablet_server_main.cc:220] Invalid argument (yb/util/universe_key_manager.cc:73): Could not init Tablet Manager: Failed to open tablet metadata for tablet: eb1e5457022f42c084148ca8fa4ba5c6: Failed to load tablet metadata for tablet id eb1e5457022f42c084148ca8fa4ba5c6: Co
uld not load Raft group metadata from /data/yugabyte/data/yb-data/tserver/tablet-meta/eb1e5457022f42c084148ca8fa4ba5c6: Key with version number c7b91fad-dd60-404f-8846-cab568e52468 does not exist.
    @     0x7fcdace5ee4c  yb::LogFatalHandlerSink::send()
    @     0x7fcdaa5e28ee  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fcdaa5dfa7a  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fcdaa5e3169  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @           0x4124ea  yb::tserver::(anonymous namespace)::TabletServerMain()
    @     0x7fcda6811825  __libc_start_main
    @           0x410f99  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
```

The only way to start it up is remove the old data.

My steps were:
1.- Cluster up with 3 server
2.- Create a taable with 3 partition on different tablet id confirmed via UI)
3.- Insert 3 different row to diff partition
4.- Select * working fine
5.- Shut down one Table server
6.- Select * working fine
7.- Starting up the table server (error)

We are running using config file:

```
/usr/local/yugabyte/src/yugabyte-2.11.0.1/bin/./yb-tserver --flagfile /data/yugabyte/etc/tserver.conf
```

and config:

```
--tserver_master_addrs=ip1:7100,ip2:7100,ip3:7100
--rpc_bind_addresses=fqdn
--server_broadcast_addresses=ip1
--enable_ysql
--pgsql_proxy_bind_address=ip1:5433
--cql_proxy_bind_address=ip1:9042
--fs_data_dirs=/data/yugabyte/data
--placement_cloud=cloud
--placement_region=reg
--placement_zone=zone
--use_client_to_server_encryption=true
--certs_for_client_dir=/data/yugabyte/ssl
--certs_dir=/data/yugabyte/ssl
--use_node_to_node_encryption=true
--ysql_enable_auth=true
--log_dir=/data/yugabyte/logs
--ssl_protocols=tls12,tls13
--ysql_pg_conf=pgaudit.log='DDL',pgaudit.log_level=notice,pgaudit.log_client=ON,log_min_messages=notice,log_line_prefix='\%m \%r \%u \%d [\%p]'
```

Looks like the key is not in memory:

```
/usr/local/yugabyte/src/yugabyte-2.11.0.1/bin/yb-admin -master_addresses $master get_universe_config
```

```
{"version":2,"replicationInfo":{"liveReplicas":{"numReplicas":3,"placementBlocks":[{"cloudInfo":{"placementCloud":"cloud","placementRegion":"region","placementZone":"zone"},"minNumReplicas":1}]}},"clusterUuid":"dccea8cb-9790-48ba-8a05-6218a8e875a4","encryptionInfo":{"encryptionEnabled":true,"universeKeyRegistryEncoded":"sZTzNciYu6b1KxZonpJx6v7CDDvexiv1jh/HIEAOkpV4YRrIZbIK9jtajdEMmVEUy706+dmz8bmnZvy6/n33u+qS7fzRSOTPOlpxYI6+k1lSM6bu2DRTTffhZtaiKN15gy8a3ifaZV7xJ9QJ3z9SvFYzb96+KDWw","keyPath":"/data/yugabyte/rest/universe_key","latestVersionId":"c7b91fad-dd60-404f-8846-cab568e52468","keyInMemory":false}}
KeyInMemory: False
```

We are using encryption at rest but the the file with the key should be there.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
usr/local/yugabyte/src/yugabyte-2.11.0.1/bin/yb-admin -master_addresses fqdn:7100 all_masters_have_universe_key_in_memory 7e13c99e-5278-4abd-ab78-79f70d6c2679
Error running all_masters_have_universe_key_in_memory: Operation failed. Try again. (yb/tools/yb-admin_client_ent.cc:1027): Unable to check whether master has universe key in memory.: Node fqdn:7100 does not have universe key in memory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error seems to indicate the tserver is looking for a key - “c7b91fad-dd60-404f-8846-cab568e52468” in order to open the file, but can’t find it.

Realizing that there’s an actual key file on the masters. That’s been deprecated for using more secure in-memory keys. I just did a little digging through the code, and sure enough, we don’t actually support sending on-disk keys to tablet servers on restart.

The command you have to run is this one:

```
yb-admin -master_addresses <master-addresses> add_universe_keys_to_all_masters <key_id> <key_path>
```

and then right after that it should work:

```
/usr/local/yugabyte/src/yugabyte-2.11.0.1/bin/yb-admin -master_addresses $master all_masters_have_universe_key_in_memory 1
Node fqdn1:7100 has universe key in memory: 1
Node fqdn2:7100 has universe key in memory: 1
Node fqdn3:7100 has universe key in memory: 1
```